# Do full bleed laser printers exist?

Tags: print-design, prepress

I was told that full bleed laser printers do not exist because the toner is too messy. Today, I stumbled upon [this video](http://youtu.be/2NSODPkvwfI) (it's in Dutch, sorry) that claims to do full bleed high volume printing. I couldn't tell if it was a laser printer or not but usually these printers are (or am I wrong?)

This model is a little too large for what we are doing (approximately 4000 color / 5000 black per month). On the smaller models I don't see this "full bleed" feature.

Have I been fooled into believing the salesman about full bleed and laser printers? Or are they using oversize paper and cutting it in the finisher (or something else)?

Also, this business printer market is quite opaque for an outsider like me, is there any transparent comparison source (website or mag) for this niche?

Comment: I work at a local retail print place and the only printers we have that do full bleed are all inkjet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal way to acheive "full bleed" on A3 for example is to print on bigger paper such as A£+ or SRA3 & trim the white space off?
Most decent laser printers and copiers will take these sizes, I sell Xerox kit and know that they do.
I hope this helps?
Regards
Mike